# C#: Insert, delete, save, cancel buttons for tabledata

Tags: c#

I'm doing a project with a group of fellow students at Aalborg University - Denmark, where we have to code an IT-system. We are using C# and now we are stucked from further progression. I'm working with a part of the system where an admninistator can handle different tables from a database. I can get the tables displayed in a datagrid by choosing which one by using a combobox.
Now the problem is that i can't figure out how make a save, delete, insert and clear/cancel buttons that can handle the specific selected table and update the right one, eventhough i've tried multiple soultions but none of them seems to work.
The DataSet contains 5 tables:
DataSet = p4DataSet.
The tables: customer_table, employee_table, shop_table, order_table and product_table.

Hope someone can help with a suggestion how to make this work.

This is the code i have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data;

namespace AdminFinal
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter daTableinfo;
        DataSet dsTableinfo;

        string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=p4;port=3306;password=fordgt40;charset=latin1;";

        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Kunder")
                {

                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                    try
                    {
                        label2.Text = "Connecting to MySQL...";

                        string sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_table";
                        daTableinfo = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daTableinfo);

                        dsTableinfo = new DataSet();
                        daTableinfo.Fill(dsTableinfo, "customer_table");
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsTableinfo;
                        dataGridView1.DataMember = "customer_table";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        label2.Text = ex.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Ansatte")
                {

                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                    try
                    {
                        label2.Text = "Connecting to MySQL...";

                        string sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_table";
                        daTableinfo = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daTableinfo);

                        dsTableinfo = new DataSet();
                        daTableinfo.Fill(dsTableinfo, "employee_table");
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsTableinfo;
                        dataGridView1.DataMember = "employee_table";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        label2.Text = ex.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Produkter")
                {

                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                    try
                    {
                        label2.Text = "Connecting to MySQL...";

                        string sql = "SELECT * FROM order_table";
                        daTableinfo = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daTableinfo);

                        dsTableinfo = new DataSet();
                        daTableinfo.Fill(dsTableinfo, "order_table");
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsTableinfo;
                        dataGridView1.DataMember = "order_table";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        label2.Text = ex.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Ordre")
                {

                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                    try
                    {
                        label2.Text = "Connecting to MySQL...";

                        string sql = "SELECT * FROM product_table";
                        daTableinfo = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daTableinfo);

                        dsTableinfo = new DataSet();
                        daTableinfo.Fill(dsTableinfo, "product_table");
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsTableinfo;
                        dataGridView1.DataMember = "product_table";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        label2.Text = ex.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Butikker")
                {

                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                    try
                    {
                        label2.Text = "Connecting to MySQL...";

                        string sql = "SELECT * FROM shop_table";
                        daTableinfo = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daTableinfo);

                        dsTableinfo = new DataSet();
                        daTableinfo.Fill(dsTableinfo, "shop_table");
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsTableinfo;
                        dataGridView1.DataMember = "shop_table";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        label2.Text = ex.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    label2.Text = "Vælg en tabel at arbejde med...";
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.p4DataSetBindingSource.AddNew();

        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.p4DataSetBindingSource.EndEdit();
          //  this.p4DataSet.UpdateAll(this.p4DataSet);
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.p4DataSetBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Nicolai, Denmark

Comment: Giving us a specific problem that you're having with your solution, rather than asking how to implement something, would be more well-received by the community. Also, changing the names of your buttons to something more descriptive (like changing `button3` to `removeButton`) would help with code readability.

Comment: brug en 
DELETE FROM table_name
 WHERE some_column=some_value;

og hvis det er nogle bestemte items du skal have slettet skal du bruge en sql command og nogle parameterværdier